# A lot of logon/logoffs events in Windows event log

Tags: windows-server-2003, security, windows-event-log, team-foundation-server

I have a server that contains Team Foundation Server which we use for source control.  This server is windows server 2003, however it is not our domain server.

When we do a large 'get latest version' on a client machine with TFS, it tends to run slow and then eventually hang.  On checking the security event log on the server I see A LOT of logon/logoff events taking place for the user account doing the get latest version.

Is it normal to have several logon/logoff events *per second* for an account continuously?

Answer (score 1):

It depends.  A logon event is really just establishing an authenticated network session, and this could be interactively, as a batch job, as a service or across the network.  TFS could well be (and I freely admit that I don't know) creating multiple sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Which user? You could have a misconfigured or misdesigned app using impersonation based security for privilage seperation but doing so in an inefficient manner.

Comment: The op states "for the user account doing the get latest version"

Comment: Correct, it is using my personal logged on user account to connect to the server.  I'm just wondering whether or not 100's of logon/offs is considered 'normal' for an application (i understand thats a pretty general statement).